# Get the inline message of xhr responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am receiving json form when submitting a contact form , and I would like to get the inline message of it ;

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { 
               setFormMessage(xhr.responseText.) // Returns a 200 response if the submission is successful.
            } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 400){ 
                setFormMessage(xhr.responseTex)); // Returns a 400 error the submission is rejected.          
            } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 403){ 
                setFormMessage(xhr.responseText); // Returns a 403 error if the portal isn't allowed to post submissions.           
            } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 404){ 
                setFormMessage(xhr.responseText); //Returns a 404 error if the formGuid isn't found     
            }
           }
```

this the message when it's 200 :

```
{"inlineMessage":"Thanks for submitting the form."}
```

I have already tried to get the value of the inlineMessage like this :

```
xhr.responseText.inlineMessage
```

but it didn't work !
any idea how to get that message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this  `xhr.responseText.inlineMessage` is not working because  you're treating the response data as an object ,  while it is JSON string

So you can parse that JSON string with a JavaScript program and access the data as an object.
you might do something  like this :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
               setFormMessage(jsonResponse.inlineMessage) // Returns a 200 response if the submission is successful.
            }
```